# How to heal workers?

Tags: civilization-5

Workers are usually captured rather than damaged, but I was recently playing with a friend, and he was bombing my workers from the see.

I was then looking for the "fortify until healed" option, but couldn't find it. Can workers heal themselves ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have a Fortify option, but if you take no action with them during the turn, they will heal the same as any other unit (1 point in neutral territory, 2 points in friendly territory, 3 points in a city).

Comment: so there is no way to have them sleep while they heal, and get the focus again when they are at full health again...

Comment: Nope, that unfortunately isn't possible.